sending data from wordpress to angular
the project I'm working on is a wordpress plugin which display an angular application. in order to do that, I prerender the angular application with Static Site Generation and put the result in the wordpress extension.
I create the project with the command ng new angular.
on the start of the application, I need to send the root url from wordpress to the angular application but I don't have found how to do that.
I tried a javascript global variable :
<script>
const server = "https:/domain/directory";
</script>
<app-root></app-root>

I tried also passing the value in a tag parameter :
<app-root server="https:/domain/directory"></app-root>
<app-root [server]="https:/domain/directory"></app-root>

in all theses tries, I don't have found how to read this value in angular.
have somebody an idea how to do that ?

Your first attempt is a local variable, not a global one. To declare a global variable, try to attach it to the window object: window.server = "https:/domain/directory"

I tried but I have no access to read in ngOnInit, window is not defined, nor server.

Try environment consts.

In the worst case, you can try to use a file as a singleton with that variable.

with SSG the consts are compiled in the global js file then I don't want to dynamically edit this file.

The typical is declare a variable in your component.ts (but outside the component)
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common'
..rest of imporst..

//here use declare var nameOfVariable

declare var server:any;

//here the definition of your component
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['..']
})
export class MyComponent {
 constructor(){
   //You can use the variable, see that have NO this.
   console.log(server)
 }
}

If it's a variable that you use so much you can create in a .ts a function
declare var server:any;

function getServer():string
{
    return server||"";
}

This allow that if you want to change the variable in the script not need look for in all yours components or services the "declare var".
In your component or service or whatever
import {getServer} from "./utils.ts"

console.log(getServer())


in my dev console I have ERROR ReferenceError: server is not defined on the line "console.log". I tried with const server = "aaa"; and window.server ... in the html code.

have you in your index.html :<script>var server="hello word"</script>? see stackblitz. See that "var" in javascript makes a variable global to all in the .html.

I have the same error with "var" or "const", no problem on building time but on execution, I have server is not defined. I point out that I create the project with the command ng new angular, that looks like the classic way of creation.

Try to write the script in "header" for all the wordpress page (I'm have no much experience with wordpress) instead of only in the page where the angular app is.

for this part, I am doing development in the little index.html of the angular project, going to wordpress is the next step when this works locally. and trying the script in header make the same error.

thank you Eliseo to try to help me. I found that your way of using a variable is cleaner that what I explained in my answer. then I really hope we can found a way of doing this work and it's for that I don't have checked my answer now ;)

after one night without sleeping and trying to use provider to pass value, I solved the mystery : the application is run one time on server side where the variable server is not defined. and in a second phase, this runs in browser where server is defined and then your code works perfectly.

I found a way of passing values.
In html code, I set this :
<app-root data-server="https:/domain/directory"></app-root>

and to read the value in the component (app.component.ts), I use this :
import {ElementRef, afterRender} from "@angular/core";

// ...

constructor(elementRef :ElementRef)
{
    
    afterRender(() => {
        
        console.log(elementRef.nativeElement.dataset["server"]);
        
    });
    
}

